# Forming partial differantial equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Form the partial differential equation by eliminating arbitrary constants of $a$ and $b$ from the equation

$2z=(ax+y)^2+b$

The problem is that I can eliminate $a$ but $b$

$2z_x=2a(ax+y) \quad\text{ and }\quad 2z_y=2(ax+y)$

if I divide them $\frac{z_x}{z_y}=a$

and i have $2z=(\frac{z_x}{z_y}x+y)^2+b  $

how to proceed further to eliminate $b$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the second equation we have
$$
a=\frac{z_y-y}{x}.
$$
then
$$
\frac{z_x}{z_y}=\frac{z_y-y}{x}.
$$

Comment: I couldnt think of this thank you for the help